# How can I change an object value in an array in react redux reducer state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, state

This is my react redux reducer

```
const initialState = {
    products: [
        {
            name: 'Icecream',
            inCart: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Cake',
            inCart: false
        }
    ]
};

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case BUY_CAKE:
            return {
                state
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I want to change the first object's inCart value to true in products array when the BUY_CAKE action is called .
How can I do it ??

Comment: Its odd, but won't you want to update the second item in products array on BUY_CAKE action

Comment: just return a new state with what ever you want to mutate. But why not put a new property "carts" and push "Cake" in once BUY_CAKE action is dispatched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say that `action.payload` is equal to the object `{name: 'Cake', inCart: true}`, then you can do something like this:

```js
const initialState = {
    products: [
        {
            name: 'Icecream',
            inCart: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Cake',
            inCart: false
        }
    ]
};

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case BUY_CAKE:
            const products = return state.products.map(item => {
              if(item.name !== action.payload.name) {
                return item;
              }
              
              return {
                ...item, 
                inCart: action.payload.inCart
              }
            })
            
            return {
              ...state,
              products
            }
            
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a map function where it iterate through all objects and find the payload name and changes inCart to true return the updated object

```js
const initialState = {
    products: [
        {
            name: 'Icecream',
            inCart: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Cake',
            inCart: false
        }
    ]
};

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case BUY_CAKE:
            return {
                ...state,
                products:state.products.map(item=>{
                     if(item.name===action.payloadName)
                       item.inCart=true
                     return item
                })
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```